# Finding fundamental solution to the biharmonic operator $\Delta^2=\Delta(\Delta)$?

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Show that when $n=2$, the function $u(x)=-\dfrac{1}{8\pi}\left\lvert x\right\rvert^2\log\left\lvert x\right\rvert$ is a fundamental solution to the biharmonic operator $\Delta^2=\Delta\left(\Delta\right)$. That is, show that $$\varphi(0)=\int_{\Bbb R^2}u(x)\,\Delta^2\varphi(x)\,dx$$ for all functions $\varphi$ smooth with compact support.

My attempt:

My first confusion: the question says it is equivalent to show $\varphi(0)=\int_{\Bbb R^2}u(x)\,\Delta^2\varphi(x)\,dx$. Why is that true? Considering the definition, I think it is $\;0=\int_{\Bbb R^2}u(x)\,\Delta^2\varphi(x)\,dx\;$ instead of $\varphi(0)$. Where am I wrong?

My second confusion is it seems I can directly compute $\Delta u=-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\Big(1+
\log\left\lvert x\right\rvert\Big)$, then it is obvious $\,\Delta\left(\Delta u\right)=0$. Is that enough for proving this question?

The calculation of $\Delta u(x)$ is as follows:
$$u_{11}=-\dfrac{1}{8\pi}\left[2\ln\left(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\dfrac{2x_1^2}{x1^2+x_2^2}+1\right)\right]$$
and 
$$u_{22}=-\frac{1}{8\pi}\left[2\ln\left(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\dfrac{2x_2^2}{x1^2+x_2^2}+1\right)\right],$$
so 
$$\Delta u=u_{11}+u_{22}=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\Big(1+\log\left\lvert x\right\rvert\Big).$$

Could someone kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: "show that..." with all the parts given usually means "run through the steps and verify it works..". In this view the second part of your attempt is correct. Now, the given problem asks to "show" the integral relation holds. By performing integration by parts to obtain the form $\int \phi(x) \, \Delta^{2}u(x) \, dx$. Knowing $\Delta^{2}u(x) = 0$ then there will be a constant term left, namely, $\phi(0)$.

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks for your comment. How to perform integration by parts? I tried and I get $\int \varphi(x) \Delta^2 u(x)=\int u(x) \Delta^2 \varphi(x)=0$ instead of $\varphi(0)$ since $\varphi(x)$ has compact support?

Comment: A sketch has been outlined. Refinement may be needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Note that $u(x)$ has a singularity at $0$ (the logarithm is not defined at $0$) and this must be dealt with. Split the integral over a ball $\mathbb{B}(0,\epsilon)$ centered at the origin and with radius $\epsilon$ and the rest of the space $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{B}(0,\epsilon)$, then analyse each integral separately. This can be written as
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}u(x)\Delta^2\varphi(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{B}(0,\epsilon)}u(x)\Delta^2\varphi(x)dx+\int_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{B}(0,\epsilon)}u(x)\Delta^2\varphi(x)dx.
\end{equation*}
Taking the modulus gives us the bound
\begin{equation*}
|\int_{\mathbb{B}(0,\epsilon)}-\frac{1}{8\pi}|x|^2\log|x|\Delta^2\varphi(x)dx| 
\leq c\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}|\Delta^2\varphi(x)||\int_{\mathbb{B}(0,\epsilon)}|x|^2\log|x|dx|.
\end{equation*}
Can you show this goes to zero as $\epsilon\to 0$ using polar coordinates? For the second integral, use the divergence theorem twice. Integrate over the boundary of the ball (denoted $\partial \mathbb{B}(0,\epsilon)$) and show everything goes to $0$.

Hope that helps!